# Does $\sum_n \frac{a_n^\alpha}{n^\beta}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does $\sum_n \frac{a_n^\alpha}{n^\beta}$ converge when $\alpha +\beta>1$ and $\sum_n a_n $converge where $\alpha>0$ ,$\beta>0$ and $a_n>0$.I have no idea to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can prove it by using young inequality,it must converge.
When $\alpha \geq 0$,we can easily get the answser,so we only need to consider $\alpha <1$.
Then we have $(a_n)^\alpha(\frac{1}{n})^\beta\leq\alpha(a_n^\alpha)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}} +(1-\alpha)(\frac{1}{n})^{\frac{\beta}{1-\alpha}}$.